# How to handle User Created Project Variables with qgis API

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a project and a plugin for a company working with QGIS 2.14.4.

I want to update - through the plugin - a user created project variable which is used for rule-based styling purposes by i am not able to find the way by reading the api.

I found a workaround by using QGIS' own project variables in particular QgsProject.instance().setTitle() and changing the layer styles' rules to use @project_title variable but this is far away from clean.

Can anyone help with how to access and change user created project (or even layer) variables?